# Are there any other known relatives of Hitler living today?

Tags: hitler

If there are relatives of Hitler living, which countries do they live in and are there any books and or biographies by them?

Comment: Lots of information here: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/1348850/Hitlers-lost-relatives-found-on-Long-Island-in-terror-of-identification.html

Comment: How far afield do you want to go? Do you care about Hitler's great grand nephew?

Comment: I disagree with those who say this question is 'trivial'; triviality is in the eye of the beholder. If this question does not interest you personally, don't read it, but don't ban other people from asking or answering . It is also not a request for 'basic historical facts' as it is disputed if e.g. Hitler had an illegitimate child. See Jay Nordlinger's book 'Children of Monsters' chapter on the Frenchman whose mother told him he was the son of Hitler following an affair during World War I.